# Quickblox Location Sample iOS application is not working

Tags: ios, xcode, quickblox

I am trying to check how Quickblox location sample iOS app is working. But I am getting error with null value in error reason . Please see below request method where I am getting error.

```
[QBRequest geoDataWithFilter:filter page:[QBGeneralResponsePage responsePageWithCurrentPage:1 perPage:70]
                        successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSArray *objects, QBGeneralResponsePage *page) {
                            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                SSLAppDelegate* myDelegate = (((SSLAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate));
                                [self presentViewController:myDelegate.tabBarController animated:YES completion:nil];
                            });
                            [[SSLDataManager instance] saveCheckins:objects];
        } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
            NSLog(@"Error = %@", response.error);
        }];
```

Where response.error value is Error reasons:(null).

I am seeking for yours help. Thanking you.

Comment: Can you post Xcode logs of request and response